# LINQ Include command mvc3 and webgrid

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, linq

I'm doing an asp.net mvc3 application similar to amazon gift card system. I have a model named Cards which is related to the models Users, cardStatus, paymentMethod and cardHistory. I'm doing a grid where I displays the data of all cards (creator, initial amount, status). I'm using a WebGrid to display the data. The card can have multiple status in time, when I added the Controller, asp generated this code:

```
public ViewResult Index()
    {
       var cards= db.cards.Include(t => t.cardStatus).Include(t => t.paymentMethod).Include(t => t.users);           

       return View(cards.ToList());
    }
```

The problem is that I need to show in the webgrid the latest card status but the generated query brings all status, so it gives me an error in the webgrid "column cardStatus.status.name doesn't exists"
Here my webgrid code:

```
@grid.GetHtml(
        headerStyle: "header",
        tableStyle: "table table-striped table-bordered table-hover",
        columns: new[] {
            grid.Column("cardId", header: "Card"),
            grid.Column("user.ID", header: "Creator"),
            grid.Column("initialAmount", header: "Amount"),
            grid.Column("cardStatus.status.name", header: "Status")
        }
```

)
I've tried some LINQ statements but I'm new at it so it did not work. How can bring all the Card info but only with the latest status? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
cardStatus
```

is a collection of all Status for a Card-object, right? I would add a property in your Card-class:

```
public partial class Card {
    public CardStatus LastStatus
    {
        get
        {
            return cardStatus.Last();
        }
    }
}
```

That would be usefull if you needed to access that last Status multiple times.
Than you could add the column in the WebGrid like that:

```
grid.Column("LastStatus.name", header: "Status")
```

You could also solve your problem with a LINQ-Query. For help on that look here: [MSDN: 101 LINQ Samples](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b) (Especially the join-operator will be useful: [LINQ - Join Operators](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/LINQ-Join-Operators-dabef4e9))

Thomas

Comment: Hi Thomas, thanks for your answer, since I haven't work with LINQ querys very much, I used your first solution, it worked perfectly, thanks a lot.